# Python TypeError comparing str and int

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror

newbie to python ... Now, I know it doesn't make sense to do something like "my_string > 4"
However, here is my code:

```
my_dict= {}
my_list= []
with open ("test.startStop.pileup") as pileup:
    for line in pileup:
        if not line.startswith('#'):
            fields = line.split('\t')
            if fields[2] > 4:
                my_dict[fields[0]] = my_list.append(fields[1], fields[2])
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Here is the start of my pileup file, so I skip the line starting with "#". But then, fields[2] should be an integer right?

```
#RefName    Pos Coverage
chromosome_1    0   0
chromosome_1    1   0
chromosome_1    2   0
chromosome_1    3   0
chromosome_1    4   0
chromosome_1    5   0
chromosome_1    6   0
chromosome_1    7   0
chromosome_1    8   0
```

What's wrong ? 
any help greatly appreciated
thanks

Comment: Try printing “fields[2]” before assigning to dictionary. And  observe the results. Also Append takes only one argument you provided two

Comment: I just figured it out, I should do int(fields[2]). You are correct about append, this will be changed.